# Custom module to override CategoryController.php not working

Tags: magento-1.7, overrides, custom

To dodge the max of 1000 products in a category I tried to override CategoryController.php. I think I did everything right, but the module doesn't work. I'm working with Magento 1.7.0.2 Community Edition.

In code/local/EM/CategoryFix/etc/config.xml I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
        <EM_CategoryFix>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </EM_CategoryFix>
    </modules>
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <adminhtml>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <CategoryFix before="Mage_Adminhtml">EM_CategoryFix_Adminhtml</CategoryFix>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </adminhtml>
        </routers>
    </admin>
</config>
```

In code/local/EM/CategoryFix/Adminhtml/Catalog/CategoryController.php:

```
require_once 'Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/CategoryController.php';
class EM_CategoryFix_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_CategoryController
{  
   //public function to override
}
```

And in etc/modules/EM_CategoryFix.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <EM_CategoryFix>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </EM_CategoryFix>
    </modules>
</config>
```

I checked everything a thousand times, what do I miss?

Comment: Try this line `<EM_CategoryFix before="Mage_Adminhtml">EM_CategoryFix_Adminhtml</EM_CategoryFix>`  You should use `EM_CategoryFix` instead of `CategoryFix`.

Comment: add`<depends><Mage_Adminhtml/></depends>` at EM_CategoryFix.xml

Comment: @KingshukDeb, thanks for your input. I tested it, but is doesn't do the trick. After saving the category, the quantity of products gets reduced to 1000.

Comment: @Ellen-RosevanDijk i only told you how your override should work. You were trying to override a core class and that was not working. Thats why i told you that thing. Now its your code which should check 1000 products max.

Comment: @KingshukDeb, I understand ;) The code works if I put it in the core file, but I don't want to adjust a core file. That's why I would like to put it in a custom module. But so far, I can't get my module to work unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

**Location of rewrite controller is wrong**

```
app/code/local/EM/CategoryFix/Adminhtml/Catalog/CategoryController.php
```

**it should be**

```
app/code/local/EM/CategoryFix/controllers/Adminhtml/Catalog/CategoryController.php
```

Also
add `<depends><Mage_Adminhtml/></depends>` at `EM_CategoryFix.xml`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I tried both options, also together, but unfortunately it doesn't do the trick. After saving the category it still reduces the quantity of products to 1000.